# Foreign key as required field on Django 1.5 configurable user model, createsuperuser says: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_state'

Tags: django, manage.py, django-1.5

Using the new [Configurable user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#configurable-user-model) from Django 1.5 (1, 5, 0, 'beta', 2) I get this error while running [manage.py createsuperuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser) trying to set a foreign key of a required field:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_state'

Since I've a [fixtures/initial_data.yaml](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures) with values I need for my user model, workflow is:

1. Create database
2. python manage.py syncdb
3. Answer "no" to the question *You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined. Would you like to create one now? (yes/no)*
4. *Installed 14264 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)*
5. python manage.py createsuperuser

I try to create superuser after fixtures are imported, so this is not a problem caused by an empty database table for the City model.

Code excerpt, based on [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#a-full-example):

**models.py**

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=70, help_text="City.")
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, help_text="State.")
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['city']
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.city, self.state)

class PersonaManager(BaseUserManager):
    [...]
    def create_superuser(self, email, name, birthplace, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(email,
            password=password,
            name=name,
            birthplace=birthplace,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Person(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    birthplace = models.ForeignKey('myapp.City', related_name="person_birthplace")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = PersonaManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'birthplace']
```

How can I get the foreign key working on my user model on a required field? Thank you.

Edit:
Traceback from `manage.py createsuperuser --traceback`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asd/Envs/envdjango15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/asd/Envs/envdjango15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 252, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/asd/Envs/envdjango15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 112, in handle
    user_data[field_name] = field.clean(raw_value, None)
  File "/home/asd/Envs/envdjango15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 211, in clean
    self.validate(value, model_instance)
  File "/home/asd/Envs/envdjango15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1014, in validate
    using = router.db_for_read(model_instance.__class__, instance=model_instance)
  File "/home/asd/Envs/envdjango15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 142, in _route_db
    return hints['instance']._state.db or DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_state'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_state'
```

Comment: Where is the complete stacktrace?

Comment: I've executed createsuperuser with traceback option: I've included the result above.

Comment: Are you using multiple databases in your ptoject?

Comment: No, I'm using a single database. Anyway, just omitting the otherwise compulsory fields in create_superuser definition avoid this issue.

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988183/cant-create-super-user-with-custom-user-model-in-django-1-5

Comment: You have `ForeignKey('myapp.City'...`
Isn't `ForeignKey(City...` enough?

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure that this will fix it, but just for kicks, tack on the PermissionsMixin and yank off the is_superuser off your model.

Perhaps there is some sort of permission checking thing going on in the background - granted it should not be happening but give it a shot.

My suspicion comes from the concept of it trying to sniff out what model permissions it needs to apply.