# Can't create super user with custom user model in Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

my goal is to create a custom user model in Django 1.5

```python
# myapp.models.py 
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company')
    ...

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['company']
```

I can't create a super user because of the company field (models.ForeignKey('Company') (python manage.py createsuperuser).
My question:
How can I create a super user for my application without a company.
I tried to make a custom MyUserManager without any success:

```python
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    ...

    def create_superuser(self, email, company=None, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Or do I have to create a fake company for this user?
Thank you

Comment: Why company is required?

Comment: In my model, a user without a company can't exist. But there is an exception for the superuser. I got this error without REQUIRED_FIELDS : IntegrityError: app_myuser.company_id may not be NULL

Comment: You can specify a default company for all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three ways for you in this case

1) Make relation to company Not required `company = models.ForeignKey('Company', null=True)`

2) Add default company and provide it as default value to foreign key field `company = models.ForeignKey('Company', default=1)`  #where 1 is id of created company

3) Leave model code as is. Add fake company for superuser named for example 'Superusercompany' 
set it in create_superuser method.

UPD: according to your comment way #3 would be the best solution not to break your business logic.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to your feedback here is the solution I made:
A custom MyUserManager where I created a default company

```python
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, company=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """

        if not company:
            company = Company(
                name="...",
                address="...",
                code="...",
                city="..."
            )
            company.save()

        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            company=company
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```